# Irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{8}$. How do I determine the (isomorphism classes) irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$? I do not know how to approach such a problem, and if someone can give a general approach to finding the irreducible representations of a finite $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Assume that $\rho:G\to GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ is an irreducible representation. Consider the matrix $A=\rho(\overline{1})$. Because $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, it has an eigenvector $v\in\Bbb{C}^n$. As $\rho$ is a homomorphism, we have $A^8=I_n$, so the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ mist satisfy $\lambda^8=1$. Anyway, we see that for all $k=0,1,\ldots,7$ $A^kv=\lambda^kv$. This means that the 1-dimensional subspace $M$ spanned by $v$ is a subrepresentation. By irreducibility of $\rho$, we have $M=\Bbb{C}^n$, so $n=1$.

Comment: (cont'd) Furthermore, any eighth root of unity can serve in the role of $\lambda$, and distinct eighth roots give rise to non-isomorphic irreducible representations.

Comment: This generalizes to show that all the irreducible reps of abelian groups are 1-dimensional. It is easy to show that all the matrices representing elements of the group are diagonalizable. As they commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. The claim follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are entire books written about finding irreducible
[representations of finite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups)  over the complex field.
You should consult these for general details. It is known that all 
irreducible representations of a finite abelian group have degree $1$.
More specially, the irreducible representations of a finite cyclic 
group are all powers of a linear representation generator as follows.

Suppose that $\,n>0\,$ is an integer, a multiplicative group 
$\,G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}\,$ with generator $\,g\in G,\,$ and 
$\,\zeta:=e^{2\pi i/n}.\,$  The linear mappings
$\, \rho_k(g^j): z\to \zeta^{kj}z\,$ (where $\,z\in\mathbb{C}\,$
and $\,\mathbb{C}\,$ is regarded as a one dimensional complex vector
space over itself) for all integer $\,0 \le k < n\,$
are all of the irreducible representations of $\,G.\,$ These are
all degree one linear maps and hence $\,\chi_k(g^j) := \zeta^{kj}\,$
are also all the irreducible characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb Z_8$ is a finite abelian group, every irreducible finite-dimensional representation of $\mathbb ZZ_8$ is actually $1$-dimensional and it is given by an action of $\mathbb Z_8$ on $\mathbb C$ given by $g.v=\varphi(g)v$, where $\varphi\colon\mathbb Z_8\longrightarrow\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

My Maschke's theorem, $\mathbb C[G]$ is a semisimple ring for any finite group, that is, it is a finite product of matrix rings over $\mathbb C$.  (Maschke's theorem is more general, but the claim that the matrices are all over $\mathbb C$ depends on the algebraic closedness of $\mathbb C$.)

If additionally $G$ is abelian, then you have to have that all the matrix rings are trivial, so that $\mathbb C[G]\cong \mathbb C^{|G|}$.

In a finite product of fields, you can exhibit all isoclasses of simple modules by listing the ideals you get by selecting an index $i$ in the product and zeroing out entries outside of that index.

That covers your case.  The case of nonabelian $G$, you'd have to consider the simple submodules of matrix rings: however each one of them only contributes a single simple submodule to the product, so it is not much harder.